# Installing OpenGeo suite breaks tomcat on an instance of AWS Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, boundless-suite, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am running an instance of Ubuntu Server 12.04 on AWS and after installing the OpenGeo suite have been unable to get access to tomcat6 via localhost:8080 and thus no access to the OpenGeo dashboard.

What I have tried so far: allowed access to port 8080 in AWS, disabled the firewall locally, reinstalled OpenGeo numerous times, and used netstat to see that tomcat is not listening. I have installed Apache and it does listen to port 80.

What is interesting is that I can access tomcat when installed without the OpenGeo suite but once I install the suite I can no longer access it. I am new to Linux and at a loss. If necessary, let me know which logs would be helpful to post.

---

I have come to the conclusion that OpenGeo/OpenPlans intentionally cripples the Community edition of OpenGeo Suite on Amazon-EC2 in order to sell their package for a fee version. Fair enough but I can't afford to pay them and Amazon while I learn.

---

Solved (with help from [Don Meltz](http://www.donmeltz.com/opengeo-suite-3-0-on-a-micro-aws/)). Because of the limited memory available in a micro-instance a swap file must be created for tomcat to work. This was unrelated to OpenGeo.

Comment: The only difference between the Community Edition and the Enterprise Edition of Suite is that Enterprise adds a few extra plugins.  Crippling the Community Suite in any way would be completely counter productive as the point is really to sell support contracts, not the software itself, and the software is available for free piecemeal anyway.

Comment: I understand your point and appreciate your comment as you seem knowledgeable on the subject. Do you have any idea as to why the Community Edition of the OpenGeo Suite will not install correctly on Amazon-EC2? It seems that certain WAR files are not installed (blocked?) compared to my vm version of Ubuntu Server 12.10 running locally. Any input is appreciated.